# Dynamic update of a razor page

Tags: vue.js, razor, asp.net-ajax

I am intending to build a fairly comprehensive (read: complex) search form using razor pages in a dotnet core webapp. One of the features of this page will (I intend) be live/dynamic updates (search results refresh as search parameters are typed/chosen) and that the displayed browser URL is updated to reflect the search parameters as they are changed.

In order to prepare for this I've been looking for documentation on how to build this page and it seems to me that while Razor pages are easy (fun?) to build for basic page designs, having dynamic (read: partially refreshed) components requires the use of more basic (read: not framework supported) JavaScript.

While I have found articles [like this](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/form-post) which document how to do the 'live update' I'm not sure if this is really the best approach.

I don't know if frameworks like VueJS (which would be the alternative option, due to in-house skill set) make dynamic/live updating of the browser URL any easier (by virtue of their framework features).

Does VueJS, though it is more front-end heavy, provide a stronger platform for developing a live/dynamic refreshed page than Razor pages or am I simply missing some fundamental (perhaps too easy?) feature of Razor pages which provides for quick/easy development of dynamic, partial page updates?